# Audit SELECT on a particular column

Tags: oracle, oracle-18c

How do I do audit `SELECT` on one column in the table?

The column in question is a BLOB column so most likely these blob columns are accessed using some `dbms_lob`.

Table Emp:

| column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| Emp_Id | Number |
| Ename | Varchar2(40) |
| Emp_Image | Blob |

`SELECT` on `Emp_Image (dbms_lob)` should generate an audit record.

Do I need to use `dbms_fga`?

I'm using Oracle Database 18C.

I have not tried anything, just exploring options. I know standard audit can do select,DML on full table but not on one column of a table. `DBMS_FGA.ADD_POLICY( object_schema => 'hr', object_name => 'emp', policy_name => 'finegrained_hr_emp_check', audit_column => 'emp_image' statement_types => 'select');` This is what I can think off. There are some enhancements in audit called uniform auditing but unable to find example for such scenario.